# quickfixj swaps group order

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

I want to produce a market data request with 2 groups, `NoMDEntryTypes` (267) and `NoRelatedSym` (146) one after the other, as below:

```
267=2 269=0 269=1 146=1 55=EUR/USD
```

but when I send the message somehow quickfixj or my data dictionary swaps around the order of the groups to the following:

```
146=1 55=EUR/USD 267=2 269=0 269=1
```

This happens even if I create a direct string message and validate it through my data dictionary.

What can I do to keep the groups in the order I want ?! THANKS

Comment: The QuickFIX/J code generation includes an "orderedFields" option to order regular body fields by the data dictionary ordering. I'm not sure if this will order repeating groups but it might be worth trying if you really need to order groups for some reason. http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.3/usage/codegen.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define class extending GROUP and use your own order for it.
just check NoMDEntryTypes.NoRelatedSym

Comment: Thanks Dev at Transferwise :-)

Comment: Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63827638/in-quickfix-what-is-the-relatedsymgroup-order-set-by) I got it to work extending `group`

Comment: I don't understand how this could be relevant.  The original question is not about reordering tags within groups, but about reordering groups within the top-level body! 
 146 and 267 are not within a group, so what group could you extend?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier there is a `protected Message(int[] fieldOrder)` constructor which allows define explicit field order. Hence it is possible to inherit this type and create your custom message with given order.

Answer (score 5):

In FIX, the order of tags in the top-level body does not matter.  The various QuickFIX engines' internal representations of `Message` objects ignore the top-level tag order, because there is no benefit to storing it.  When the message is converted to a string, it orders them by numerical tag order.  **It doesn't change the message in any meaningful way according to FIX.**

(Order is preserved inside of repeating groups, because FIX does mandate that the ordering is meaningful inside of groups.)

> What can I do to keep the groups in the order I want ?!

For QuickFIX, the answer is: **You *can't*.**

If that is a really big problem for your needs (there's no reason it should be), then I guess you'll have to explore other FIX engine options.

Comment: Thx Grant... So why is the ordering swapped at all?

Comment: Because the `Message` class stores the top-level body fields in a `HashMap` (I think) that is keyed by tag.  Hashes do not preserve order.  It would require extra coding to store the order information, which would not be worthwhile because FIX doesn't care about the order.