# how to read FIX 4.4 feed from server in C#

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I'm developing an application that read all the SECURITIES REQUEST of FIX 4.4. My concern only how to  Get All Securities/Indices of a Trading Session (Market).

**Example**

Get All Securities/Indices of a Trading Session (Market)
Here the client is requesting all securities of one trading session.

**Request:**
8=FIX.4.4|9=126|35=x|34=394|49=FIX00801|52=20161208-12:24:49.390| 56=PSX |115=008| 143=REG |60=20161208-
12:24:49.390| 320=1122|336=REG|460=5 |55=NA|559=3|10=009|
FIX adapter will send all securities in multiple fragments, 100 securities in each fragment

**Response:**
8=FIX.4.4|9=9997|35=y|34=41553|49=PSX|52=20161208-12:24:50.891| 56=FIX00801
|320=1122|322=0|393=611|560=0|893=N|146=100|55=PKGP|48=ISIN_CODE|22=4|460=5|106=Pakgen Power
Limited.|107=Pakgen Power Limited.| 336=REG| 55=HUSI | 48=ISIN_CODE |22=4|460=5|106=Husein Industries|107=Husein
Industries|336=REG|
55=SMBL|48=ISIN_CODE|22=4|460=5|106=TBILL01810270|107=TBILL01810270|336=REG|55=PKGS|48=ISIN_CODE|22=
4|460=5|106=Packages Ltd.(XD)|107=Packages td.(XD)|336=REG|55=BWHL|48=ISIN_CODE |22=4|460=5|106=Baluchistan
WheelsLtd.| 107=BaluchistanWheels Ltd.|336=REG|55=FRSM|48=ISIN_CODE|22=4|460=5|106=Faran Sugar Mills Ltd.|107=Faran
Sugar Mills Ltd.|336=REG|10=031|….. Repeat for 100 symbols.

Comment: What is the exact question? Does this answer your question: http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/repeating-groups.html it talks about how to read repeating groups out of a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you’re asking about repeating groups. You could take a look at this question and the linked questions and answers

[In QuickFix what is the RelatedSymGroup order set by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63827638/in-quickfix-what-is-the-relatedsymgroup-order-set-by)

Comment: Basically, my concern only with fix protocol as a listener, how I can read all feed/ tick in .net.